# How to use the ToolButton clicked signal (in a HeaderBar)?

Tags: gtk, vala, genie

While creating a simple ToolButton, one can use the clicked.connect interface as in the [Toolbar example from the Vala guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/GTKSample). The interface of adding a button to a [HeaderBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258764/how-to-pack-a-button-in-a-headerbar-using-genie/36279563#36279563) is similar to what is shown in that example. However, the way of handling the clicked connection seems to be different (or there is something that I am missing).

The following example is of a small text editor, where a open dialog button is packed into the HeaderBar. The clicked.connection syntax, however returns an error.

Here is the code:

```
[indent=4]
uses
    Gtk

init
    Gtk.init (ref args)

    var app = new Application ()
    app.show_all ()
    Gtk.main ()

// This class holds all the elements from the GUI
class Application : Gtk.Window

    _view:Gtk.TextView

    construct ()

        // Prepare Gtk.Window:
        this.window_position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER
        this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit)
        this.set_default_size (400, 400)


        // Headerbar definition
        headerbar:Gtk.HeaderBar = new Gtk.HeaderBar()
        headerbar.show_close_button = true
        headerbar.set_title("My text editor")

        // Headerbar buttons
        open_button:Gtk.ToolButton = new ToolButton.from_stock(Stock.OPEN)
        open_button.clicked.connect (openfile)

        // Add everything to the toolbar
        headerbar.pack_start (open_button)
        show_all ()
        this.set_titlebar(headerbar)

        // Box:
        box:Gtk.Box = new Gtk.Box (Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 1)
        this.add (box)

        // A ScrolledWindow:
        scrolled:Gtk.ScrolledWindow = new Gtk.ScrolledWindow (null, null)
        box.pack_start (scrolled, true, true, 0)

        // The TextView:
        _view = new Gtk.TextView ()
        _view.set_wrap_mode (Gtk.WrapMode.WORD)
        _view.buffer.text = "Lorem Ipsum"
        scrolled.add (_view)
```

The open_button.clicked.connect returns at compilation:

```
text_editor-exercise_7_1.gs:134.32-134.39: error: Argument 1: Cannot convert from `Application.openfile' to `Gtk.ToolButton.clicked'
        open_button.clicked.connect (openfile)
```

Does the way of handling that signal changes when one uses the HeaderBar widget?

The code is working as long as the line is commented (you may want to add a stub for the openfile function).

Thanks

**UPDATE**

This question deserves an update, because the error was actually not in the body I attached above.

The error was at the definition of the function. I wrote:

```
    def openfile (self:Button)
```

When I should've instead:

```
    def openfile (self:ToolButton)
```

Or simply:

```
    def openfile ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the click handler in your code, using this example stub it works just fine:

```
def openfile ()
    warning ("Button clicked")
```

So I guess that the type signature of your click handler is wrong and that's why the compiler is complaining here.